# Issue using [Regex]::Match in powershell

Tags: regex, string, powershell, match

I am trying to extract an URL from the Body of a Mail in PowerShell.

I am using following regex: (found on [this site](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex))

```
$regexURL = "@^(https?|ftp)://[^\s/$.?#].[^\s]*$@iS"
```

then I loop into a Mail folder and for each mail-item:

```
foreach ($Mail in $subfolder.items)  {    
    $a = [Regex]::Match($Mail.Subject, $regexURL).Groups[1].Value
    $b = [Regex]::Match($Mail.Body, $regexURL).Groups[1].Value
}
```

But even when Mail.Subject or Body contains a valid URL, $a and $b stay empty.

I am afraid I did not understand how is Match() working.

Thanx for any help on that question.
Jerome

Comment: Indentation! Please fix it before posting!

Comment: Please post an example of `$Mail.Subject` and what you expect `$a`to be.

Comment: What's the `@` good for? Seems to be regex for another language. Try `$regexURL = '(https?|ftp)://[^\s/$.?#].[^\s]*$'`. `iS` modifiers is not required in PS/.NET AFAIK.

Comment: $Mail.Subject could be "http://www.stockoverflow.com" for instance. $Mail.Body the same with empty lines at the end. '(https?|ftp)://[^\s/$.?#].[^\s]*$' is not working at all. For the time being only "(http[s]?|[s]?ftp[s]?)(:\/\/)([^\s,]+)" is a little bit (!) working and gives "http" back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex is for another language (PHP probably), so you need to modify it to the .NET syntax. Powershell is case insensitive by default and `S` is an optimizing modifier for PHP I think, so we'll skip both of those. Try:

```
$regexURL = '(https?|ftp)://[^\s/$.?#].[^\s]*$'
```

Sample:

```
$regexURL = '(https?|ftp)://[^\s/$.?#].[^\s]*$'

#URL
[regex]::Match("test http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604481/issue-using-regexmatch-in-powershell/36605171?noredirect=1#comment60807898_36605171", $regexURL).Groups[0].Value
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604481/issue-using-regexmatch-in-powershell/36605171?noredirect=1#comment60807898_36605171

#Protocol
[regex]::Match("test http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604481/issue-using-regexmatch-in-powershell/36605171?noredirect=1#comment60807898_36605171", $regexURL).Groups[1].Value
http
```

Comment: Yup, .NET doesn't use modifiers, so `@^` is basically the equivalent of `(?!)` here.

Comment: I think you found the point but it is still not working. I tried now with: "(http[s]?|[s]?ftp[s]?)(:\/\/)([^\s,]+)" and it gives back "http" in $b. I have still to find the right regexUrl for PowerShell 5.

Comment: It does exactly what it should. You have `http` (protocol) in a capture group`()`. The match itself is in group 0. See sample in updated answer